# Degrees of Separation of actors in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a huge prolog database of actors e.g

```
actor('adam_zweibel','the_story_of_us',1999,20).
actor('alan_zweibel','north',1994,10).
actor('alan_zweibel','the_story_of_us',1999,21).
actor('darrell_zwerling','...and_justice_for_all',1979,32).
actor('darrell_zwerling','capricorn_one',1978,21).
actor('darrell_zwerling','chinatown',1974,6).
actor('darrell_zwerling','doc_savage:_the_man_of_bronze',1975,6).
actor('darrell_zwerling','high_anxiety',1978,15).
actor('darrell_zwerling','joe_versus_the_volcano',1990,15).
actor('darrell_zwerling','the_main_event',1979,45).
actor('darrell_zwerling','la_mortadella',1971,0).
actor('darrell_zwerling','the_secret_life_of_an_american_wife',1968,0).
actor('darrell_zwerling','wild_at_heart',1990,40).
actor('michael_zwiener','big_bully',1996,15).
```

I need to implement something like this

```
?- within_degree('johnny_winter', 'matthew_witherly', 3, X).
X = [sgt_peppers_lonely_hearts_club_band, keith_carradine, crisscross, paul_calderon, bait] ;
X = [sgt_peppers_lonely_hearts_club_band, morgan_farley, heaven_can_wait, larry_block, bait] ;
X = [sgt_peppers_lonely_hearts_club_band, 'steve_martin_(i)', bowfinger, jamie_kennedy, bait] ;
X = [sgt_peppers_lonely_hearts_club_band, 'steve_martin_(i)', my_blue_heaven, larry_block, bait].
```

Something like build a tree of actors which has two endings Actor1, Actor2.
I don't know how to start, could someone please help me out or throw an idea how to approach this task. Thanks

Comment: No need for quotes if you use `_` in place of spaces!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea to approach the task.

First just worry about detecting if they are connected:

- Actor1 and Actor2 are connected by degree 1 if they are in the same movie
- or they are connected by degree N if Actor1 is connected to Actor3 by degree N-1 and Actor3 is connected to Actor2 by degree 1

Try writing a predicate connected(+Actor1,+Actor2,+Degree) which implements that. This predicate will return true if the two actors are connected by the degree and will return false if they are not.

Next step is to add in the list of results you want i.e.

- Actor1 and Actor2 are connected by degree 1 through the list of [M].
- Actor1 and Actor2 are connected by degree N through the list which you get by appending: the list of steps from Actor1 to Actor3, Actor3 and the list of steps from Actor3 to Actor2

Comment: Two actors shouldn't be necessarily connected. For example, 
`?- withindegree('jack_palance', 'mos_def', 1, X).
false.`
but 
`?- within_degree('jack_palance', 'mos_def', 2, X).
X = [che, 'benjamin_bratt_(i)', the_woodsman] ;
X = ['city_slickers_ii:_the_legend_of_curlys_gold', bill_mckinney, wheres_marlowe] ;
X = [solar_crisis, 'peter_boyle_(i)', monsters_ball] .`

Comment: Not sure I understand you. My answer above will give you false if they are not connected. Could you clarify?